# whatsapp api: delay in sending the message

Tags: facebook, whatsapp, whatsapi

I have created a message template and it will be approved. When I send a message

```
curl -i -X POST \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/210679105452960/messages \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer token' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{ "messaging_product": "whatsapp", "to": "380630000000", "type": "template", "template": { "name": "sms_code_en", "language": { "code": "en" }, "components": [{"type": "body", "parameters": [{"type": "text", "text": "123123"}]}] } }'
```

it comes after 30-40 seconds. But when I send the message from the example

```
curl -i -X POST \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/210679105452960/messages \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer token' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{ "messaging_product": "whatsapp", "to": "380630000000", "type": "template", "template": { "name": "hello_world", "language": { "code": "en_US" } } }'
```

It comes very quickly, a few seconds. Perhaps someone has encountered and can tell what is the matter?

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been around since July 2023 and to this day they have not resolved this problem.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35842274)